# Different results when using nodal and mesh analysis; application on a Thevenin equivalent problem

Tags: thevenin, nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

I need to find the Thevenin equivalent  of the given circuit. The problem is that when I use Nodal analysis and mesh analysis I get different results. I know that Rth = 16 Ω. But when I use nodal analysis I get that Vth = 255.6 V and when using mesh analysis I get that Vth = 336 V.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Nodal analysis: (at point x as shown in the first picture)

(180 - V1)/10 + 12   = V1/40
V1 = 159.6 V

So Vth = Vax + Vxb = 96+159.6 V = 255.6 V

With mesh analysis:

-180 + 10(Ia - 12) + 40Ia = 0

Ia = 6 V

Vth = Vax + Vxb = 96 + 240 = 336 V

P.S. this is not a homework question.

[image: mesh analysis]

[image: nodal analysis]

Comment: *"this is not a homework question."* I'll take you at your word. But that `30%` over there on the left sure makes it look like one. I'll look over your work, shortly.

Comment: All you need to do is to check your math for the nodal part. [Solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28180+-+V%29%2F10+%2B+12+%3D+V%2F40)

Comment: You are correct.I am really sorry for asking a question like this .

Comment: Should i delete this question ?

Comment: No. May I ask in which country this strange-looking current source symbol is used? And the "omega" (\$\Omega\$) symbol?

Comment: It's from greece, which explains the omega symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad to hear that you feel you have this in the bag, so to speak.

Just to help you verify your own thinking, let me solve this for you in both ways. For starters, let's lay out the schematic:

[image]

Note that there is also some *unknown* voltage across \$I_1\$. So I'm calling that \$V_{I_1}\$. We can work that out, later.

*(I've unfortunately used \$I_1\$ for two different purposes above: one for a mesh current and another for the \$12\:\text{A}\$ current source. Context will have to be your guide. I am stuck with the decision I made earlier.)*

Also, we will take it that \$V_{_\text{B}}=0\:\text{V}\$, by definition. (We are grounding it.) We get to do that for exactly one node. And I think this is the better one to call.

We will need \$I_{_\text{TEST}}\$ in order to work out, fully, the Thevenin equivalent. So note that \$V_{_\text{TEST}}\$ is the voltage across it. (But this is just \$V_{_\text{A}}-V_{_\text{B}}=V_{_\text{A}}\$.)

### Mesh

For KVL analysis, we have two loops to work out. I'll take these loops starting in the lower left corner of each loop:

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V} + V_1 - R_1\cdot\left(I_1-I_2\right) - R_2\cdot \left(I_1-I_3\right) &= 0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V} + V_{I_1} - R_3\cdot \left(I_2-I_3\right) - R_1\cdot\left(I_2-I_1\right) &= 0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V} - R_2\cdot\left(I_3-I_1\right) - R_3\cdot\left(I_3-I_2\right) - V_{_\text{TEST}}&= 0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

This can be solved for \$I_1\$, \$V_{I_1}\$, and \$V_{_\text{TEST}}\$. (We don't need \$I_2\$ because we already know that \$I_2=12\:\text{A}\$ and we don't need \$I_3\$ because we already know that \$I_3=-I_{_\text{TEST}}\$.)

Using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) and remembering that \$I_3\$ is the negation of \$I_{_\text{TEST}}\$:

```
specified = { r1:10, r2:40, r3:8, v1:180, i2:12 }
e1 = Eq( 0 + v1 - r1*(i1-i2) - r2*(i1-i3), 0 )
e2 = Eq( 0 + vi1 - r3*(i2-i3) - r1*(i2-i1), 0 )
e3 = Eq( 0 - r2*(i3-i1) - r3*(i3-i2) + vitest, 0 )
ans = solve( [ e1, e2, e3 ], [ i1, vi1, vitest ] )
ans[vi1].subs(specified).subs( i3, 0 )
156
ans[vi1].subs(specified).subs( i3, -1 )
172
```

So from mesh (KVL) we find that \$V_{_\text{TH}}=V_1+V_{I_1}=180\:\text{V}+156\:\text{V}=336\:\text{V}\$ (test current is 0, here.) We also find that \$R_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{V_1 + 172\:\text{V}\,-\,\left(V_1+156\:\text{V}\right)}{1\:\text{A}\,-\,0\:\text{A}}=16\:\Omega\$.

### Nodal

From KCL analysis, find:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_{_\text{X}}}{R_1}+\frac{V_{_\text{X}}}{R_2}+\frac{V_{_\text{X}}}{R_3}&=\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_2}+\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{R_3}
\\\\
\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{R_3}&=\frac{V_{_\text{X}}}{R_3}+I_1+I_{_\text{TEST}}
\end{align*}$$

Using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```
e4 = Eq( vx/r1 + vx/r2 + vx/r3, v1/r1 + 0/r2 + va/r3 )
e5 = Eq( va/r3, vx/r3 + i1 + itest )
ans = solve( [ e4, e5 ], [ vx, va ] )
ans[va].subs(specified).subs( itest, 0 ).subs( i1, 12 )
336
ans[va].subs(specified).subs( itest, 1 ).subs( i1, 12 )
352
```

So from nodal (KCL) we find that \$V_{_\text{TH}}=336\:\text{V}\$ (test current is 0.) We also find that \$R_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{352\:\text{V}\,-\,336\:\text{V}}{1\:\text{A}\,-\,0\:\text{A}}=16\:\Omega\$.

Same as before.

### Summary

Both methods give the same result. Good thing.